# Is there a way to multiple users share the same machine simultaneously?

Tags: gratis, ubuntu

I recently started a scientific initiation in a laboratory at my university. We are a little short of money and in need of new computer. Is there any free program (for Ubuntu, preferably) that allows two users too log in and use the machine simultaneously for diferent purposes?

Comment: for sure: ubuntu itself... just create another user.

Comment: But will I be able to connect multiple screens and keyboards?

Comment: Linux runs on very old PC & laptops, so you might get a really cheap one. It also runs on Raspberry Pi, and you can get a Pi 3 for US $40 or so

Answer (score 3):

There is something on Ubuntu called [MultiSeat](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX):

> a single machine that supports multiple concurrent users each with
>   their own set of keyboards, mice, and monitors providing a traditional
>   desktop experience to each user.

Please see the link for more details.

Also, there is the [SE Ubuntu forum](https://askubuntu.com/) for more specific questions.

Comment: This. Or use old machines as X terminals (enough Linux local to boot and start X, then query a remote server via XDMCP and log in there)

Comment: Does it still work? Ubuntu's help page hasn't been updated for almost 6 years (since 2013) and the Ubuntu versions mentioned (10.x, 12.x, 13.x) are no longer maintained

Comment: There are some more recent links with comments here that seem to suggest it works https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054541/multiseat-on-ubuntu-18-04 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017811/setting-up-multiseat-the-easy-way-on-ubuntu-16-04 . You'd have to try it yourself. The alternative is to use some old machines as suggested above.